# ImportError: cannot import name 'int' from 'numpy'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

I am trying to import `sklearn` library by writing code like `from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler` but it kept showing same error.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no change. Command prompt is also giving same error. Recently I installed some python libraries but that never affected my enviroment.

I also tried running the code in jupyter notebook. When I tried to import `numpy` like `import numpy as np`, it ran successfully. So the problem is only with `sklearn`.

Also, I have worked with `sklearn` before but have never seen such an error.

Comment: It's probably a version mismatch. The most recent `numpy` as removed `int`, saying instead you should just use `int`.  But `np.int` is still scattered around in old versions of other packages.  Did you try an update on `sklearn`?

Answer (score 5):

Run `pip3 install --upgrade scipy`
OR upgrade whatever tool that tried to import `np.int` and failed
`np.int` is same as normal `int` of python and scipy was outdated for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to read into the error message. For me sklearn was importing something from scipy which uses the outdated np.int, so updating scipy solved the issue for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading NumPy to an older version through `pip install numpy==1.19` in Anaconda Prompt worked for me.  It seems likely in my case that a specific version of a library trying to import `np.int` caused the error.